# Obtener resultado de un tabla que hace referencia a otra tabla en 2 de sus campos

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Tengo una tabla `consulta`, a la cual se le puede agregar 2 diagnostico, estos valores los obtiene de otra tabla llamada `diagnosticos`:

*Tabla `consulta`:

- id
- motivo
- diagnostico1
- diagnostico2
- receta

*Tabla `diagnosticos`:

- id
- nombre

Al seleccionar los valores de la tabla consulta ¿Como obtengo los nombres del diagnostico1 y diagnostico2?

```
SELECT c.id, c.motivo, d.nombre as "diagnostico1", c.diagnostico2, c.receta
FROM consulta as c
INNER JOIN diagnostico as d
WHERE c.diagnostico1=d.id;
```

Se puede desde la consulta que me ponga el nombre del diagnostico de cada uno o es mas eficiente obtener los indices y mediante una funcion en mi html busque el nombre de ese diagnostico?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algo así:

```
SELECT c.id, 
       c.motivo, 
       d1.nombre as "diagnostico1", 
       d2.nombre as "diagnostico2", 
       c.receta
       FROM consulta as c
       LEFT JOIN diagnostico as d1
            ON c.diagnostico1=d1.id
       LEFT JOIN diagnostico as d2
            ON c.diagnostico2=d2.id
       ;
```

Detalle:

- Hacemos dos `LEFT JOIN` a una misma tabla para acceder a los nombres de los dos dignosticos
- El secreto del punto anterior es usar un alias de tabla distinto, en este caso `d1` y `d2`
- Uso un `LEFT` ya que no tengo seguridad que la consulta tenga uno o los dos diagnósticos, usando un `INNER` la consulta debería tener los dos, sino esta consulta no sería mostrada.
- En cuanto a que es más óptimo, siempre que las tablas tengan los índices adecuados, hacer una única consulta que retorne todos los datos suele ser más performante, que dividir la misma en dos consultas independientes.

Comment: saludos Patricio, tengo una pregunta; yo no veo una FK que vincule a ambas tablas, por lo tanto mi duda es, aún así se puede hacer uso de JOINS?

Comment: @element, si, el JOIN es independiente de las claves y los índices, puedes usar cualquier columna, obviamente hacerlo sobre una que no tengan índices tendrá una penalidad importante en la performance.

Comment: muchas gracias por la aclaración te doy +1, pues no sabía nada al respecto de lo que me comentas, pensé que siempre debía ser sobre una PK y una FK y que si no simplemente no funcionaba

Comment: Gracias, efectivamente asi lo hice pero usando el inner join, como mencionas al no tener un valor (por que si es opcional el segundo diagnostico) no me mostraba la consulta, lo que hice es que el segundo diagnostico tuviera un valor por default desde la tabla, asi que solo pueden escoger un valor para el diagnostico de 2 en adelante (el id 1 se lo reserve al valor por default)

Como comenta son independientes de  las PK, en mi caso se relacionan desde diagnostico1 y diagnostico2 que son FK en la tabla consulta y en la tabla diagnostico la PK es el id (se me olvido especificarlo)

Answer (score 1):

también puedes usar subquerys, si es que tiene problemas con el concepto de JOIN

```
SELECT c.id, 
      ,c.motivo
      ,(SELECT nombre FROM diagnosticos
        WHERE  id = c.diagnostico1) as diagnostico1
      ,(SELECT nombre FROM diagnosticos
        WHERE  id = c.diagnostico2) as diagnostico2
       c.receta
FROM   consulta as c
```

Comment: funciona pero el performance se ve comprometido